# Why is ASP.NET not deserializing my post method parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, telegram-bot

I am trying to learn the basics of ASP.NET. I decided to try to make a telegram bot and my first step is to get it to loop back my messages to it. I am using [Telegram.Bot](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot) as my client. I set up the project using VS Code connected remotely to a Ubuntu 20.04 machine next to my windows PC (which I am working from). `dotnet --version` says I am running 3.1.4 (on the linux machine). I ran `dotnet new mvc -o telegram-odin`. Then I added the BotController class seen below. I have used this class to test various endpoints and methods. Just feeling out how to do things. I have my telegram bot token stored in an environment variable on the linux machine. I am using ngrok to allow telegram's webhooks to post back to me.

My issue is that I can't seem to get any post endpoints to correctly accept objects. I tried using [Telegram.Bot's webhook example](https://github.com/TelegramBots/telegram.bot.examples/tree/master/Telegram.Bot.Examples.WebHook), but this just doesn't work. Update is always null, and the `Request.Body` is always empty. I have searched around and found other people with issues of null objects when using the [FromBody] attribute, but they all talked about receiving primitive types instead of objects. I did see that someone mentioned that something called "Middleware" might be consuming the body when I use [FromBody]. So I removed it and tried to parse the `Request.Body` directly. I found that I would get a default (the same as the result of `new Update()`) value for update, but more importantly the `Request.Body` has the JSON data that I can grab and parse. Theoretically I am in business now and can just deserialize it. However, I feel like I should be able to let ASP.NET just handle that for me. So something must be wrong.

My configured services.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddSingleton<TelegramBotClient>(new TelegramBotClient(Program.GetBotToken()));
}
```

My Controller class.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Telegram.Bot;
using Telegram.Bot.Types;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;

namespace telegram_odin.Controllers
{
    public class BotController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<BotController> _logger;
        private readonly TelegramBotClient _telegramClient;

        public BotController(ILogger<BotController> logger, TelegramBotClient telegramClient)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _telegramClient = telegramClient;
            // I know I am resetting the endpoint every time one of these endpoints is called. 
            // I will fix this later.
            var botClient = _telegramClient;
            botClient.SetWebhookAsync(GetWebhookInEndpoint());
        }

        public async Task<string> Index()
        {
            var botClient = _telegramClient;
            var me = await botClient.GetMeAsync();
            return me.ToString();
        }

        public async Task<string> GetWebhookInfo()
        {
            var botClient = _telegramClient;
            var webhookInfo = await botClient.GetWebhookInfoAsync();
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(webhookInfo).ToString();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Update(Update update)
        {
            try
            {
                if (update is null) 
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("update is null");
                }
                else 
                {
                    string updateAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(update);
                    _logger.LogInformation($"update as json - {updateAsJson}");
                }
                string body = "";
                using (StreamReader reader =new StreamReader(Request.Body))
                {
                    body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                }
                _logger.LogInformation($"update body - {body}");
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Problem(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        
        // I know this is the wrong place for this method.
        // Quick and dirty is the way to learn.
        private string GetWebhookInEndpoint()
        {
            // I wrote a helper to pull the https Uri by asking my local ngrok server about its' open tunnels.
            var ngrokUri = NgrokHelpers.GetNgrokUri();
            var wholeUri = new Uri(ngrokUri, "Bot/Update");
            _logger.LogInformation($"generated webhook endpoint - {wholeUri.ToString()}");
            return wholeUri.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

This is Telegram.Bot's `Update` definition.

```
#region Assembly Telegram.Bot, Version=15.7.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// Telegram.Bot.dll
#endregion

using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums;
using Telegram.Bot.Types.Payments;

namespace Telegram.Bot.Types
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     This object represents an incoming update.
    //
    // Remarks:
    //     Only one of the optional parameters can be present in any given update.
    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn, NamingStrategyType = typeof(SnakeCaseNamingStrategy))]
    public class Update
    {
        public Update();

        //
        // Summary:
        //     The update's unique identifier. Update identifiers start from a certain positive
        //     number and increase sequentially. This ID becomes especially handy if you're
        //     using Webhooks, since it allows you to ignore repeated updates or to restore
        //     the correct update sequence, should they get out of order.
        [JsonProperty("update_id", Required = Required.Always)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Optional. New incoming message of any kind — text, photo, sticker, etc.
        [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public Message Message { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Optional. New version of a message that is known to the bot and was edited
        [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public Message EditedMessage { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Optional. New incoming inline query
        [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public InlineQuery InlineQuery { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Optional. The result of a inline query that was chosen by a user and sent to
        //     their chat partner
        [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public ChosenInlineResult ChosenInlineResult { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Optional. New incoming callback query
        [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public CallbackQuery CallbackQuery { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Optional. New incoming channel post of any kind — text, photo, sticker, etc.
        [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public Message ChannelPost { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Optional. New version of a channel post that is known to the bot and was edited
        [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public Message EditedChannelPost { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Optional. New incoming shipping query. Only for invoices with flexible price
        [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public ShippingQuery ShippingQuery { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Optional. New incoming pre-checkout query. Contains full information about checkout
        [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public PreCheckoutQuery PreCheckoutQuery { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     New poll state. Bots receive only updates about polls, which are sent or stopped
        //     by the bot
        [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public Poll Poll { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Optional. A user changed their answer in a non-anonymous poll. Bots receive new
        //     votes only in polls that were sent by the bot itself.
        [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public PollAnswer PollAnswer { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the update type.
        //
        // Value:
        //     The update type.
        public UpdateType Type { get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is possible that there is a serialization error when you use FromBody attribute. Check for some error in controller static property ModelState

Comment: I added [FromBody] again and noticed everything worked properly. The object is being correctly deserialized now. I stopped for a moment and considered what I have changed recently. The only thing I changed recently was adding Newtonsoft to my services. I did not notice that in their example. I SWEAR I built and tested this after adding that and it changed nothing.

However, I removed it from my configure services (while leaving [FromBody]) and things were broken as before. I added it to my services again (keeping [FromBody]) and everything resumed working. 

Why does it NEED this service?

Comment: Your suggestion was correct. The ModelState showed a serialization error when I removed the Newtonsoft service.

base.ModelStatebase = {"$.message.chat.type":{"ChildNodes":null,"Children":null,"Key":"$.message.chat.type","SubKey":{"Buffer":"$.message.chat.type","Offset":15,"Length":4,"Value":"type","HasValue":true},"IsContainerNode":false,"RawValue":null,"AttemptedValue":null,"Errors":[{"Exception":null,"ErrorMessage":"The JSON value could not be converted to Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.ChatType. Path: $.message.chat.type | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 206."}],"ValidationState":1}}

Comment: There is some difference how built in and Newtonsoft serializer behaves. So according to your model it has attributes from Newtonsoft(JsonProperty, JsonObject) so you should use Newtonsoft

Comment: I see. So if I built a new model that did not use Newtonsoft's [JsonProperty] attribute I would probably not have had this issue?

Comment: As you have a JSON from Body you can build a model for it. Sure.